# Why didn’t any reporters show interest towards “The Post”?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-post

Both “The Post” team & “The Times” team were brought their case to the Supreme Court for illegally giving the public access to the Pentagon Papers.

[image]

After the Court session concluded, reporters gathered near “The Times” but showed no interest in “The Post”.

Why didn’t any reporters show interest towards “The Post”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After the Court session concluded, reporters gathered near “The Times”

This is not quite accurate.

[image]

The reporters were already there in a specific spot *waiting* for a statement. It just so happened that the team from *The Times* exited first, approached them and started giving their statement.

The reporters probably would have approached *The Post* as well but they decided that no additional statement was necessary.

> Times Lawyer - "We should make a statement."
>
> Bradlee - "I think that's her job."
>
> Katherine Graham - "I believe everything we had to say we've already said."